# asp.net mvc 3: reverse of modelbinder while serializing to url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

In our application we have an object which is called a search descriptor. We have a custom modelbinder for it to make it all work.
It reads certain know properties like q oorsort and page from the URL (or post data).

Now somewhere else in the application, we need a URL to the searchpage. We use the searchdescriptor class to model what we want to search for.

I needed a way to convert all the things in searchdescriptor to a routevaluedictionary and then merge that with the action name and controller name.

No a big deal, I just added it to the class. However, modelbinders let me extend mvc before my controller kicks in, I want something similar for serialization to URL.

We also use T4mvc, but passing a complex object to an action method just serializes it to the tostring.

Does this mechanism already exist? Or do we have to code this ourselves?

Comment: Did you get any where with this? I have exactly the same problem of wanting to generate a url from a view model and having to write a reverse modelbinder myself

Comment: We ended up only needing this for a couple of models, which we could do with just custom toQueryString code and t4mvc's 0-parameter action methods. My problem actually was that I can't provide a modelbinder :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now the mechanism does not exist.
We ended up only needing this for a couple of models, which we could do with just custom toQueryString code and t4mvc's 0-parameter action methods.